# Do you know of a book on Greek philosophy with a Corinthian helmet on the cover?

Tags: reference-request, aristotle, plato

I read it years ago, and it seems I have lost it. The biggest thing I can remember is that it had a Corinthian helmet on the front cover. Also that it was translated by multiple authors and it had maybe hundreds of exerts from Aristotle, Plato and many others. This book was my birthing into philosophy, but I didn't recognize the significance of it until a couple of years ago. timeous

Comment: Maybe [Auden's Portable Greek Reader](https://www.amazon.com/Portable-Greek-Reader-Library/dp/0140150390)? What size was the helmet, and when was it published, roughly? Did "many others" include modern philosophers from Descartes on, or was it just ancient ones?

Comment: thanks so much  that was it exactly.